# "Ampla Demais" e "Não Clara" podem ser "Qualidade Muito Baixa"?

Tags: debate

Já aconteceu de acabarem meus votos para **fechar uma pergunta** e eu identifiquei que a fecharia como **ampla demais** ou **não está clara o suficiente**.

Nesses casos, posso **sinalizar** a pergunta como **qualidade muito baixa** ou estaria fazendo errado?

Comment: Uma pergunta ampla pode ter qualidade, o problema é a resposta que seria muito ampla. Já *Não Clara* pode ser sinônimo de *Qualidade Muito Baixa*, porque uma pergunta com baixa qualidade é difícil de compreender.

Comment: Lendo o descritivo de cada caso, me leva a entender que nem sempre um será o outro, apesar de dar a entender isso. Uma pergunta ampla pode estar bem escrita e está clara e continuar sendo ampla. Uma pergunta "Não clara" pode estar bem redigida mas faltar informações relevantes e continuar sendo não clara. Ambos os casos não se trata de baixa qualidade, que é algo mau redigido, de dificil leitura e interpretação.

Comment: Vamos nos atentar ao descritivo na hora de avaliar: `Esta pergunta tem graves problemas de formatação ou conteúdo. É improvável que esta pergunta seja recuperável por meio de edição e talvez seja necessário removê-la.` Veja bem, qualidade baixa quase sempre é algo de difícil compreensão e que somente o autor poderá tornar a recuperação viável, ou seja, nem sempre os outros dois casos de fechamentos cairão ai, apesar de ser possível ser um dos dois e casos e ainda sim ser baixa qualidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A descrição da sinalização de baixa qualidade diz que a pergunta provavelmente não poderá ser "salva" através de edições.

Uma pergunta muito ampla pode ser editada para ter seu escopo reduzido. Uma pergunta que não está clara o suficiente geralmente pode ser salva quando o autor inclui informações que faltam na pergunta. Logo, edições são bem-vindas nesses casos.

Portanto, a sinalização de baixa-qualidade não deve ser usada nesses casos - o fato da pergunta ser ampla ou faltar-lhe informação não implica em baixa-qualidade, e vice-versa.

Outra coisa: [as vezes o motor do SO pega uma pergunta pra levar pra fila de revisão. Nesses casos a opção de baixa qualidade fica indisponível.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278833/2263584) É o caso desta própria pergunta neste exato momento. O motivo é que o sistema já sabe que a pergunta é problemática, marcar ela de novo desse jeito não vai ajudar muito.